# How To Move RadGridView(in Telerik) Selected Row UP and DOWN In C#?

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I want to skip to the above or the next row when I use up or down button on the RadGridView (in Telerik).
The below image shows my purpose:
[image: RadGridview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void btnUP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv != null)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                dgv.GridNavigator.SelectPreviousRow(1);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}


private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv != null)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                dgv.GridNavigator.SelectNextRow(1);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this a genuine self-answer, or just a code snippet that belongs in the question instead?

Comment: This is a genuine self-answer.